# form state lost in Flask template

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

in a jinja2 template I have :
one form
then a table containing a submit button for some lines (a second form)

when this code is executed

```
selectionBatchFormBis=f.SelectionBatchForm()
listBatchCampagneBis=bDAO.getListBatchCampagneParametres(liste_campagnes=[2018,2019],liste_batch_state=["à faire","achevé KO"],liste_calendrier_batch=["ce mois ci","en retard"])
batchformBis=f.BatchForm()

return render_template("listeBatchs.html",
                           listBatchCampagne=listBatchCampagneBis,
                           batchform=batchformBis,
                           selectionBatchForm=selectionBatchFormBis)
```

the table is correctly rendered so listBatchCampagne=listBatchCampagneBis works well.
**BUT the selection form (selectionBatchForm) has no active selection (meaning 0 checkboxes are checked).**

I don't undestand why because elsewhere in my code the form is correctly rendered with the correct active selection.
The code of the form is

```
class SelectionBatchForm(FlaskForm):
campagne2018=BooleanField('2018', default="checked")
campagne2019=BooleanField('2019', default="checked")

batch_state_a_faire=BooleanField('à faire', default="checked")
batch_state_en_cours=BooleanField('en cours')
batch_state_acheve_ok=BooleanField('achevé OK')
batch_state_acheve_ko=BooleanField('achevé KO', default="checked")

calendrier_avance=BooleanField('en avance')
calendrier_ce_mois_ci=BooleanField('ce mois ci',default="checked")
calendrier_en_retard=BooleanField('en retard', default="checked")

submitSelectionBatchForm = SubmitField('valider les filtres')
```

Yours sincerely
Loïc

Comment: Did you check your code in the template?

Comment: yes i did  check my code in the template : when i render the template for the first time the rendering of the  SelectionBatchForm  is correct. It's when i submit the BatchForm that the new rendering of SelectionBatchForm is incorrect.